# Read Excel version NPOI Error

Tags: c#, .net, excel, npoi

I am trying to read an Excel file, 97-2003 or 2007-2010 version, but when I try to read the time, it gives me the following error:

> The supplied spreadsheet seems to be excel 5.0/7.0 (BIFF5)format. POI
>   only BIFF format (from excel versions 97/2000/xp/2003)

Does anyone know how to read an Excel sheet and  store it in a SQL table with C#. Also, could you guide me on the error I'm getting?

```
private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HSSFWorkbook hssfwb;
    using (FileStream file = new FileStream(@"C:\Book1.XLS", FileMode.Open,
                                            FileAccess.Read))
    {
        hssfwb = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
    }

    ISheet sheet = hssfwb.GetSheet("Sheet1");
    for (int row = 0; row <= sheet.LastRowNum; row++)
    {
        if (sheet.GetRow(row) != null) //null is when the row only contains empty cells 
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Row {0} = {1}", row,
                sheet.GetRow(row).GetCell(0).StringCellValue));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately NPOI does not support the BIFF5 format, this format is from Excel 5 and is different and incompatible with the excel 97 version. This page http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/freexl-1.0.0e-doxy-doc/Format.html gives a good background. The key quote is:

> Unexpected Revelation #1: *There is no .xls file format. Its really a common file suffix applied to many different things.*

What you need to do is convert the file to a more recent version of excel, there are a few tools that can do this, but I haven't found one I can use in my environment (shared server).

Answer (score 0):

In order for NPOI to determine the Excel type for you, you should use the **NPOI.SS.WorkbookFactory** class.  This will give an interface IWorkbook, which masks the difference between the 2003 and the 2007 versions.  The factory will create either a HSSFWorkbook or an XSSFWorkbook based on the file type.

Here is a quick example:

```
FileStream _fileStream = new FileStream(filenamePath, FileMode.Open, 
                                      FileAccess.Read);
IWorkbook _workbook = WorkbookFactory.Create(_fileStream);
_fileStream.Close();

ISheet _worksheet = _workbook.GetSheetAt(0);
```

This [post](http://www.leniel.net/2014/01/npoi-2.0-automatic-format-type-identification-inference-for-excel-2003-2007-with-iworkbook.html#sthash.CaLOHW6F.dNACGSAC.dpbs) is a good overview of the different, and the author has other NPOI related posts as well.

Comment: To save people's time, I would like to point out the `WorkbookFactory` exists since version 2. If you don't find this `WorkbookFactory`, please check the POI version in your system. Make sure it is at least version 2.